# moving wamp sql data folder to NAS

Tags: windows-7, samba, wamp, readynas

I have installed WAMP2.2 on a windows 7 machine.
now I want to move the mysql data files to my NAS.

so I tried to stop the WAMP server, change the `datadir` in `my.ini` to point to `//mynas/share/some/path` and restart the wamp server.
my window application log shows the following:
`Can't create test file \\mynas\share\some\path\MY_WINDOWS_MACHINE_NAME.lower-test`
and the `mysql.log` file shows the following:
`File '.\mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13)`

I also tried specifying IP instead of `mynas` thinking maybe its a problem of multiple credentials on a single UNC share but it did not help either.

Also tried to modify the local mysql service to use a user instead of the local system account but no go this way either.

The NAS is a netgear readynas.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.x.y\data folder to the location you specified on your NAS. Mysql controls itself using its own databases in that folder.